# Canvas Colors overwrite eachother

Tags: javascript, canvas, lines

Need to draw different color objects for a project and even though I am closing paths and beginning paths the strokestyles keeps overwriting eachother. When opened in the browsers my circle becomes green instead of yellow and all of my lines become red instead of the colors that they are supposed to be

```
function init(){
var drawBtn, clearBtn;

drawBtn = document.getElementById('drawBtn');
drawBtn.onclick = draw;

clearBtn = document.getElementById('clearBtn');
clearBtn.onclick = clearCanvas

clearCanvas();
}

function drawCircle(circle, ctx){
ctx.fillstyle = circle.color;

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.arc(circle.centerX, circle.centerY, circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.strokeStyle = 'Black'
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.closePath();
}

function draw(){
var canvas =
    document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var top = 80;
var left = 130;
var high = 200;
var wide = 300;

var top2 = 50;
var left2 = 90;
var high2 = 160;
var wide2 = 260;

var cirleft = 250;
var cirtop = 120;
var myRadius1 = 110;

ctx.beginPath;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'Blue';
ctx.moveTo(30,50);
ctx.lineTo(120,150);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath;

ctx.beginPath;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'Green';
ctx.moveTo(100,50);
ctx.lineTo(170,125);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath;

ctx.beginPath;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'Red';
ctx.moveTo(80,95);
ctx.lineTo(30,75);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath;

ctx.beginPath;
ctx.fillStyle = 'Blue';
ctx.fillRect(left, top, wide, high);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath;

ctx.beginPath;
ctx.fillStyle = 'Green';
ctx.fillRect(left2, top2, wide2, high2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath;

var myColor1 = 'Yellow';

var myCircle1 = {
    centerX: cirleft,
    centerY: cirtop,
    radius: myRadius1,
    fillStyle: myColor1
}
drawCircle(myCircle1, ctx)
}

function clearCanvas(){
var canvas, ctx;
canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have various problems in your code:**

- `beginPath` is a function so it must be executed with `beginPath()`
- `closePath` isn't really like the closing brace of `beginPath`. closePath really just makes a straight line from the current drawing position back to the starting drawing position. `beginPath` is actually "closed" when a new `beginPath` is issued.
- `fillRect` is not a path command so you don't need to do `beginPath` before calling fillRect.
- typo: `ctx.fillStyle = circle.fillStyle;` not `ctx.fillstyle`

Here is working refactored code:

[image]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

init();

function init(){
  var drawBtn, clearBtn;

  drawBtn = document.getElementById('drawBtn');
  drawBtn.onclick = draw;

  clearBtn = document.getElementById('clearBtn');
  clearBtn.onclick = clearCanvas

  clearCanvas();
}

function drawCircle(circle, ctx){

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.centerX, circle.centerY, circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.fillStyle = circle.fillStyle;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'Black'
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.stroke();

}

function draw(){

  var top = 80;
  var left = 130;
  var high = 200;
  var wide = 300;

  var top2 = 50;
  var left2 = 90;
  var high2 = 160;
  var wide2 = 260;

  var cirleft = 250;
  var cirtop = 120;
  var myRadius1 = 110;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'Blue';
  ctx.moveTo(30,50);
  ctx.lineTo(120,150);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'Green';
  ctx.moveTo(100,50);
  ctx.lineTo(170,125);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'Red';
  ctx.moveTo(80,95);
  ctx.lineTo(30,75);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.fillStyle = 'Blue';
  ctx.fillRect(left, top, wide, high);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.fillStyle = 'Green';
  ctx.fillRect(left2, top2, wide2, high2);

  var myColor1 = 'Yellow';

  var myCircle1 = {
    centerX: cirleft,
    centerY: cirtop,
    radius: myRadius1,
    fillStyle: myColor1
  }
  drawCircle(myCircle1, ctx)
}

function clearCanvas(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<button id=drawBtn>Draw</button>
<button id=clearBtn>Clear</button>
<br>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width=450 height=300></canvas>
```